# How to check if Chrome extension is installed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have written a code to check whenever a user installs a chrome extension from my website but I am not getting it to work. See code below:

```
if(chrome.app.isInstalled){
    alert("installed");
}
else{
    alert("not_installed");
}
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Are you installing using `chrome.webstore.install`? If so, just define a callback function. See docs - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore.html#method-install

Comment: Thanks for help Rob, I managed to make this work with callback functions :)

Comment: @Rob This will no longer work as of chrome 71. `window.chrome.webstore` is now `undefined`